# Sonar Runner : Unable to extract version of Microsoft Compiler

Tags: sonar-runner

While trying to run sonar-runner on a 32 bit C++/MFC solution I got the error:

Sonar Runner : Unable to extract version of Microsoft Compiler

Here is the output:

```
11:56:44.856 INFO  - 18645 files indexed
11:57:02.381 INFO  - Quality profile for c: Sonar way
11:57:02.381 INFO  - Quality profile for cpp: Sonar way
11:57:02.540 INFO  - cpp EVALUATION [Expiration: 2015-10-13, Server: *]
11:57:02.540 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
11:57:02.747 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=207ms
11:57:02.747 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
11:57:02.749 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=2ms
11:57:02.750 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
11:57:02.754 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=4ms
11:57:02.755 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
11:57:02.759 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=4ms
11:57:02.759 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
11:57:02.764 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=5ms
11:57:02.764 INFO  - Sensor SquidSensorC
11:57:02.766 INFO  - C/C++ Preprocessor in silent mode. Relaunch the analysis wi
th "sonar.verbose=true" to see issues encountered by the preprocessor.
11:57:03.214 INFO  - Using build-wrapper output: E:\dev\ProjectDir\build
-wrapper-out\build-wrapper-dump.json
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 28.126s
Final Memory: 17M/200M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to extract version of Microsoft Compiler
```

Environment:

1. Windows 7 64 bit
2. sonarqube-5.1.2
3. sonar-runner-dist-2.4
4. build-wrapper-3.6
5. sonar-cpp-plugin-3.6
6. Java 1.8 32 bit

Any ideas what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The build-wrapper produces a file with the name 'build-wrapper-dump.json'. If you open this file you'll see that at the top there is a section called 'captures'. It looks probably like this:

```
"captures":[
{
"compiler":"msvc-cl",
"executable":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\CL.exe",
"stdout":"",
"stderr":""
}
```

While it should look like this:

```
"captures":[
{
"compiler":"msvc-cl",
"executable":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\CL.exe",
"stdout":"usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ \/link linkoption... ]\r\n",
"stderr":"Microsoft (R) C\/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x64\r\nCopyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.\r\n\r\n"
}
```

To get the missing values you need to execute the build-wrapper from the Visual Studio Command prompt. This command prompt sets some extra environment variables. Hope this helps.